# Every RSpec test run requires rake db:test:prepare or equivalent using Rails 4.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

Using Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.2.5, RSpec 3.4.4, Shoulda-matcher 3.1.1, Database_cleaner 1.4.0, PostgreSQL 9.4.5.

For every rspec (or rake spec) I have to prepare the test database.  If I don't, I receive the "Migrations are pending." message.  Everything I read tells me this is not right given Rails 4.1+.  I've taken every corrective action that I can find to no avail.

Preparing the test database means I either use "rake db:test:prepare", which is deprecated, or a series of "rake db:drop/create/migrate RAILS_ENV=test".  Either works.  A simple migrate after a test does not work as it tries to recreate all the tables though they exist.  None of these problems exist in development or on Heroku production as all migrations are processed and work fine.

Rails_helper.rb contains the command "ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!" which should control this problem.  In actual fact, that command is the one that identifies that a migration is required and throws the "Migrations are pending." message.  I tried including the command "ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate(File.join(Rails.root, 'db/migrate'))" to check and force a migration if required, but that is the same as running a new migrate and causes the problem I mentioned about recreating existing tables.

I did use "rails generate rspec:install" to rebuild .rspec, spec_helper.rb and rails_helper.rb and then update the new files to try to solve the problem.  I also migrated all of my configurations over to rails_helper.rb.  spec_helper.rb is all comments.

The failure is as follows:

```
rake spec 
Running rails_helper.rb
D:/BitNami/rubystack-2.0.0-38/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:392:in `check_pending!':  (ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError)
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:
        bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

.rspec

```
--color
--format documentation
--require rails_helper
```

rails_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
puts "Running rails_helper.rb"
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

abort("The Rails environment is not running in test mode!") unless Rails.env.test?

require 'rspec/rails'
# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!
require 'shoulda/matchers'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f; puts "File #{f}" }

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
#ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate(File.join(Rails.root, 'db/migrate'))

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.extend ControllerMacros, type: :controller
  config.include JsonSpec::Helpers
  config.render_views  # Intended to ensure that views are processed

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # ## Mock Framework
  config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"

  # rspec-rails 3 will no longer automatically infer an example group's spec type
  # from the file location. You can explicitly opt-in to this feature using this
  # snippet:
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")

  # Sorcery RSpec configuration
  # config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Controller, type: [:controller]
  # config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails::Integration, type: [:feature]
  config.include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails

  # FactoryGirl RSpec configuration
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'sprockets', '3.4.0' 
gem 'sprockets-rails', '2.3.3'
gem 'sass', '3.4.19'
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.4'
gem 'uglifier', '2.7.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '2.5.3'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '2.1.0'  
gem 'jbuilder', '2.2.13'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.5.1'
gem 'figaro', '1.1.1' 
gem 'pg', '0.18.1'
gem 'simple_form', '3.1.0.rc2'
gem 'sorcery', '0.9.1'
gem 'rolify', '4.0.0'
gem 'acts_as_tenant', '0.3.9'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '3.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.4'  
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '5.0.5'
gem 'lodash-rails', '3.7.0'
gem 'logging', '2.0.0'
gem 'smarter_csv', '1.0.19'
gem 'addressable', '2.3.8'
gem 'delayed_job', '4.0.6'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '4.0.3'
gem 'better_delayed_job_web', '1.3.12'
gem 'roo', '2.0.1'
gem 'roo-xls', '1.0.0'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '4.3.2.1'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '5.2.0'
gem 'twilio-ruby', '4.7.0'
gem 'exception_notification', '4.1.1' 
gem 'exception_notification-rake', '0.2.1' 
gem 'tzinfo-data'    
gem 'responders', '2.1.0'
gem 'rubyzip', '1.1.7'      
gem 'htmlentities', '4.3.3' 
gem 'axlsx', '2.1.0.pre'
gem 'axlsx_rails', '0.3.0'
gem 'acts_as_xlsx', '1.0.6'
gem 'spreadsheet', '1.0.3'
gem 'redis', '3.2.1'
gem 'aws-sdk', '2.1.35'
gem 'aws-sdk-core', '2.1.35'
gem 'aws-sdk-resources', '2.1.35'
gem 'phony', '2.15.10'
gem 'phony_rails', '0.12.11'
gem 'ranger', '1.1.0'
gem 'execjs', '2.6.0'
gem 'paloma', '4.2.1'
gem 'rabl-rails', '0.4.2'
gem 'gon', '6.0.1'
group :production, :staging do
  platforms :ruby do # Linux
    gem 'unicorn', '4.9.0'
  end
  platforms :mswin do # Windows
    gem 'passenger', '5.0.8'
  end
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.3'  # For Heroku
  end
group :development do
  gem 'brakeman', require: false
  gem 'web-console', '2.1.3'
  gem 'bullet', '4.14.7'
  gem 'better_errors', '2.1.1'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', '0.7.2'
  gem 'quiet_assets', '1.1.0'
  gem 'rails_layout', '1.0.26'
  gem 'meta_request', '0.4.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails-source-maps', '1.4.0'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'thin', '1.6.3'
  gem 'letter_opener', '1.3.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.5.0'
  gem 'rspec-core', '3.4.4'
  gem 'rspec-rails','3.4.2'
  gem 'rspec-collection_matchers', "1.1.2"
end
group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner', '1.4.0'
  gem 'email_spec', '1.6.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '3.1.1', require: false
  gem 'shoulda-callback-matchers', '1.1.3'
  gem 'mocha', '1.1.0'
  gem 'json_spec', '1.1.4'
  gem 'pry', '0.10.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.4.4'
  gem "faker", "~> 1.4.3"
  gem "forgery", "~> 0.6.0"
  gem "launchy", "~> 2.4.3"
  gem "selenium-webdriver", "~> 2.53.0"
end
```

database_cleaner.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

Comment: Do you  also repeatedly get this issue if you run `bundle exec rspec spec` instead of rake?

Comment: @AnthonyE  Yes, the problem is the same, which I expected given the stubs.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, I don't think you should be using `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` with DatabaseCleaner. It should be false instead and this may actually be your problem.

Comment: @AnthonyE  Well, shoot.  I was hoping that would fix it but nope.  Same problem.  It definitely was wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: You should also clean with truncation after running your suite: `config.after(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end`

Comment: @AnthonyE  Added but did not help, yet.

Comment: What does `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate:status` give you before and after your tests? Does it change at all? Also, what if you run a single model test via `rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb:100` where 100 would be  replaced with the line number of an actual test example?

Comment: @AnthonyE After prepare, all migrations are up.  After any test, all migrations are down.  The one line test you recommended ran with the same result, all up before and all down after.  Wow, curious.  Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111985/discussion-between-anthony-e-and-r-g).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is apparently a known issue with Database Cleaner in version 1.4.0 where the `schema_migrations` table is cleaned along with the rest of the database: https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner/issues/317.

The `schema_migrations` table is used internally by Rails to track migration history. Thus, when it gets cleared Rails thinks that none of your migrations have been run. The simple fix is to upgrade Database Cleaner to a version newer than 1.4.0.

Comment: 1.5.3 did fix it.  Thanks.